# RW locks with hierarchy locking

Tags: multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to build an hierarchy locking system to avoid deadlocks. Meaning break the code into layers (or levels) and at each level to only allow locks in the next level. Inside the same level you should lock with predefined order. This prevents most deadlocks.
Something like this http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/use-lock-hierarchies-to-avoid-deadlock/204801163?pgno=1

For mutex this will work like a charm but for read write locks it fails. For instance if I take a read lock and then want to turn it to write lock it means I am taking a new lock in the same level, which is forbidden with this algorithem.

How do you change the algorithm to work for RW and mutex locks? Is there some other algorithm I should consider?

PS: I am programing C++ but the question is actually rellevant as a theoretical one also

Comment: What do you mean by a read write lock?

Comment: Could you edit the question to be self-contained? If that link ever breaks, then it'll leave a question that is no longer understandable. It'll also raise the question quality when it can be read in one go.

Comment: I added, but hierarchy locking is a known algorithm so there should not be a problem

Comment: @Jackson, read write locks are exactly as you described in your answer, read lock is a shared lock which multiple threads can hold. When you write lock it you wait so the readers will finnish and take an exclusive lock

Comment: this lib does multilevel read-write locks:  https://github.com/AtakamaLLC/hilok.  where you can lock parent vs child.

Answer (score 0):

Given that a read lock on thing A can be held by more than 1 thread while a write lock must be held by only 1 thread and cannot be granted if there any read locks (my default understanding of what read and write locks are about) then you can't do this.

If threads 1 and 2 have read locks how can either of them convert the read lock into a write lock?  If you allow this then one thread has a read lock and one has a write lock. What you have to do is release your read lock and all other locks at that level and then take out a new set of locks that include your write lock. In the above scenario the write lock thread will now block until the other thread releases its read lock.

If however your read lock can only be held by a single thread then how does it differ from a write lock?  If you have the lock then you have exclusive access to the think that is locked.

Comment: you understand correctly, if thread A took at level 2 a read lock and some mutex lock and then I unlock the read lock then I am not allowed to take the write lock. because the locks have to be in consistent order in each level

Comment: @Epic In that case I think all you can do is release your existing lock(s) at this level and then re-acquire them with the write lock instead of the read lock.